# Why python-docx reads only first paragraph of a docx?

Tags: python, xml, text-parsing, python-docx

Good day!

I'm currently trying to read a text from docx file using python-docx. xml of the problem part looks like this:

<w:t xml:space="preserve">**Some text**
<w:br />
**more text**
<w:br />
<w:br />
**a bit more text**
</w:t>

So when reading it with python-docx it simply does not see "**more text**" and "**a bit more text**" parts. I assume that it happens because that each line is not framed with <w:t> and </w:t>, but the whole run also includes linebreaks.
So I'm writing code:

```
doc = docx.Document('File.docx')
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
```

Output:

**Some text**

Wanted output:

**Some text**
**more text**
**a bit more text**

Does anybody knows how to make it work using python-docx or some other library in python?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the provenance of the problematic .docx file? Is it generated by some other software or made by hand using LibreOffice or Word or perhaps GoogleDocs?

Comment: Dear @Arty Antonov, I've created a sample docx file like this both using Word 2007 and Google Docs, and both of them - using your code - read it successfully. Could you provide like to the problematic file?

Comment: Hi @scanny, This .docx is generated automatically with some software unknown to me. When trying to edit this document manually using Word 2007 the whole xml structure of the document.xml is being changed, and the problem part is framed with <w:t> and </w:t> normally, so python-docx can read the whole thing.

Comment: Hi @AvivYaniv, when trying to remove confidential info from the .docx file manually the problem part of .xml disappears. Anyway, thanks for your time.